# Limit for rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ with $1<\beta<2$ be such that $\beta^i$ is irrational for every odd integer $i$. Define $f:\mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(0)=0$ and $f(q)=\beta^{4i}$ where $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\beta^{2i-1}<|q|<\beta^{2i+1}$.
>
> Show that $f(q)=\lim_{v \to 0} f(q+v)\ \forall q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f'(q)=\lim_{v \to 0} \frac{f(q+v)-f(q)}{v}=0\ \forall q \in \mathbb{Q}$.

The derivative is $0$ follows from the first bit. But I do not know how to prove the first bit. Could someone provide a hint?

Comment: What book is this exercise from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $q>0$, the remaining case is similar. Now since $\beta^{2i-1}<q<\beta^{2i+1}$ for some $i\in\mathbb Z$ (because $\beta^i\in\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ for all odd $i$ and $q\in\mathbb Q$) you find $v$ sufficiently small such that
$$\beta^{2i-1}<q+v<\beta^{2i+1}.$$
Hence $f(q+v)=f(q)$ for $|v|\ll1$ and the claim follows.

Comment: In principle the exact same argument works for all cases. I was just too lazy to care about the sign of $q$...